# Spring Retry maxAttempts does not behave and calling more than configured

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-retry

Trying to configure spring boot retry for simple method. When set maxAttempts = 3 xecuted 9 times. When maxAttempts = 2 executed 4 times. Below is my controller class.

```
    @GetMapping("/getPendingTrailRenewals")
    public void saveUserSubscription() {
        userSubscriptionService.checkMethod();
    }
```

This is my service class which retry is configured

```
    @Override
    @Retryable(retryFor = DatabaseOperationException.class, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 100))
    public void checkMethod(){
        log.info("checkMethod executed");
        throw new DatabaseOperationException("Testing");
    }
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class RetryConfig {
    @Bean
    public RetryConfiguration retryConfiguration() {
        return new RetryConfiguration();
    }
}
```

More than expected count method executed as per the logs.

```
2023-09-25T18:15:42.260+05:30  INFO 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/api/v1]        : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-09-25T18:15:42.260+05:30  INFO 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-09-25T18:15:42.261+05:30  INFO 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-09-25T18:15:42.297+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=0
2023-09-25T18:15:42.297+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=0
2023-09-25T18:15:42.298+05:30  INFO 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.a.a.a.s.i.UserSubscriptionServiceImpl  : checkMethod executed
2023-09-25T18:15:43.298+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=1
2023-09-25T18:15:43.299+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=1
2023-09-25T18:15:43.299+05:30  INFO 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.a.a.a.s.i.UserSubscriptionServiceImpl  : checkMethod executed
2023-09-25T18:15:44.303+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=2
2023-09-25T18:15:44.305+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=2
2023-09-25T18:15:44.305+05:30  INFO 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.a.a.a.s.i.UserSubscriptionServiceImpl  : checkMethod executed
2023-09-25T18:15:44.305+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=3
2023-09-25T18:15:44.306+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry failed last attempt: count=3
2023-09-25T18:15:45.308+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=1
2023-09-25T18:15:45.308+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=1
2023-09-25T18:15:45.309+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=0
2023-09-25T18:15:45.309+05:30  INFO 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.a.a.a.s.i.UserSubscriptionServiceImpl  : checkMethod executed
2023-09-25T18:15:46.311+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=1
2023-09-25T18:15:46.311+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=1
2023-09-25T18:15:46.311+05:30  INFO 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.a.a.a.s.i.UserSubscriptionServiceImpl  : checkMethod executed
2023-09-25T18:15:47.312+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=2
2023-09-25T18:15:47.312+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=2
2023-09-25T18:15:47.312+05:30  INFO 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.a.a.a.s.i.UserSubscriptionServiceImpl  : checkMethod executed
2023-09-25T18:15:47.313+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=3
2023-09-25T18:15:47.313+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry failed last attempt: count=3
2023-09-25T18:15:48.314+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=2
2023-09-25T18:15:48.314+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=2
2023-09-25T18:15:48.314+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=0
2023-09-25T18:15:48.314+05:30  INFO 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.a.a.a.s.i.UserSubscriptionServiceImpl  : checkMethod executed
2023-09-25T18:15:49.315+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=1
2023-09-25T18:15:49.315+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=1
2023-09-25T18:15:49.315+05:30  INFO 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.a.a.a.s.i.UserSubscriptionServiceImpl  : checkMethod executed
2023-09-25T18:15:50.317+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=2
2023-09-25T18:15:50.317+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=2
2023-09-25T18:15:50.317+05:30  INFO 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.a.a.a.s.i.UserSubscriptionServiceImpl  : checkMethod executed
2023-09-25T18:15:50.318+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=3
2023-09-25T18:15:50.318+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry failed last attempt: count=3
2023-09-25T18:15:50.318+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=3
2023-09-25T18:15:50.318+05:30 DEBUG 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry failed last attempt: count=3
2023-09-25T18:15:50.323+05:30 ERROR 21340 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api/v1] threw exception [Request processing failed: com.arimac.asec.adminusermgtservice.exception.DatabaseOperationException: Testing] with root cause
```

Comment: I guess it might be related that with the fact that you placed the `@Retryable` annotation on the method implementation and not on the interface. Who knows what happens when the call goes via the fancy Spring proxies :)
Try to move the `@Retryable` annotation to your interface. I assume you have an interface as I see `@Override`. Let me know if it helps - I will then convert the comment into a proper answer.

Comment: `@EnableRetry` already adds `RetryConfiguration`, so remove the bean definition.

Comment: You may experiment with it more if you leave the annotation on the implementation and add something like `this.getClass().getName()` to the `log` output. You might be surprised to see different names than just your implementing class. Spring has always some nasty proxy surprises for us :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek it's not working same results.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you explain the OP's solution? I am lost... why did it retry 9 times when there was both `@EnableRetry` and `@RetryConfiguration`?

Answer (score 0):

Working fine after this change.

```
@Configuration
public class RetryConfig {
    @Bean
    public RetryConfiguration retryConfiguration() {
        return new RetryConfiguration();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, following what @M. Deinum said in his comment, it seems like the `@EnableRetry` annotation and the `@RetryConfiguration` bean somehow multiplied the retry? But I would expect only duplicated, not multiplied by 3.

Comment: This works because you removed the `@EnableRetry` which has the same effect as leaving the annotation, and removing the bean. It reduced the configuration to 1 instead of double.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@Bean` for the `RetryConfiguration`, the same configuration class is already automatically imported when you add [`@EnableRetry`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/annotation/EnableRetry.html). Hence doubling the configuration.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class RetryConfig { }
```

When you have both the annotation and the `@Bean` method you get a double proxy/interceptor for the retry logic. Each interceptor will do the configured number of retries, however the inner one will do the configured number of retries each time it gets called.

So when the retry count is 2, the outer interceptor will call the inner interceptor twice, which will fail only after executing each call twice as well. Now when increasing the number to 3 it the outer will, eventually, call the inner interceptor 3 times, which on each call will execute 3 retries as well.